# javascript ,strict mode ,break point has effet on the result?

Tags: javascript

My code:

```
'use strict';
var foo=function(){
    alert(this);
}
var bar = {
    baz:foo,
};
var x = bar.baz;
x();//1
```

When I execute directly, all fine, alert `undefined`. When I insert the break point at (1), press F11 twice, alert `window`.

Can any one explain it? Thanks very much.

Comment: Correct your code first

Comment: @Phoenix ,i know the code looks strange,but no errors,execute normal.So what's wrong with it? could you speak clearly?

Comment: @meagar note the `use strict`,no break point,alert undefined

Comment: After foo declaration you should close statement with `;`. And can you show as some other part of code because in my case it works perfectly

Comment: @Phoenix all code is here.My friends and I get the same result.no break point ,alert `undefined`;with break point at (1),press F11,alert `window`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/3rQzs/) and check it. I added breakpoint in `1` and when I use F11 `console.log` or `alert` (I changed alert to log in final example) show me `undefined`...But then I stop at breakpoint and call in browser dev tools console `x()` the result is scope object in Mac OS X/ Chrome last version and result is `undefined` for Mac OS X/ Firefox las version.

So the result of executing in none-standart thread like dev tools console is different and has no relation to the javascript language.

Comment: thanks. but the result in debug mode is different from that in standard mode,it is so strange...Are there  any  articles to explain it?

Comment: Because browser use wrapper for debug thread like Gecko use [XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/XPCOM) or Blink use own V8 shell/debug server [implementation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink.git/+/master/Source/bindings/v8/PageScriptDebugServer.cpp).